# create video from images but repeat the first and the last frame 100 times

Tags: ffmpeg

I have images in  a specific order in a directory

Order of Images is as follows

```
frame2_0000.jpeg

frame2_0001.jpeg

frame2_0002.jpeg

frame2_0003.jpeg

....

....

,etc
```

I generate the video with the following command

```
"ffmpeg -y -r 23 -i  location_of_image_folder/frame2_%04d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -s 1280*1024 -movflags faststart location_of_output_location.mp4"
```

Now I want to create a video such that the first frame is repeated 100 times to create the video and the last frame is repeated 100 times.

What strategy should I employ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file list containing all your image file names, but duplicating the first and last 100 times:

```
1.jpeg
1.jpeg
1.jpeg
......
2.jpeg
3.jpeg
....
```

Then:

```
cat $(cat list.txt) | ffmpeg -y -framerate 25/1 -i - -f image2pipe -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -y -framerate 25/1 -i - -f image2pipe` should be `ffmpeg -y -framerate 23/1 -f image2pipe -i -` as the format is an input option here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ffmpeg -framerate 23 -loop 1 -i location_of_image_folder/frame2_0000.jpeg
        -framerate 23 -start_number 1 -i location_of_image_folder/frame2_%04d.jpeg
        -framerate 23 -loop 1 -i location_of_image_folder/frame2_1000.jpeg
        -filter_complex "[0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=100[pre];
                         [2]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=99[post];
                         [pre][1][post]concat,scale=1280:1024,setsar=1"
        -c:v libx264 -movflags faststart location_of_output_location.mp4"
```

I've assumed the first image is `frame2_0000.jpeg` and last is `frame2_1000.jpeg`. Change accordingly. You'll have to alter `start_number` as well to have a number of the file after the first image file.